# Objective C iPhone programming a dot or shape to follow your cursor

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

How would I create a program so a dot starts in the center, and when I click the screen the dot follows where I clicked? Not as in teleports to it, I mean like changes it's coordinates towards it slightly every click. I get how I could do it in theory, as in like

```
if (mouseIsClicked) { 

    [mouseX moveX];
    [mouseY moveY];

}
```

And make the class that mouseX and mouseY are have some methods to move closer to where the mouse is, but I just don't know any specifics to actually make it happen. Heck, I don't even know how to generate a dot in the first place! None of those guides are helping at all. I really want to learn this language though. I've been sitting at my mac messing around trying to get anything to work, but nothing's working anywhere near how I want it to.

Thanks for helping a total newbie like me.

Comment: How do you click a phone screen?  How do you use a mouse with an iPhone?

Comment: What I was meaning was with the simulator. As in when I click on the simulator to get it to function like so.

Comment: You should read about handling touches and the responder chain.

Comment: Yessir, I will. I read that guy's comments and I'm studying them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the sample code [here](https://github.com/EmperiorEric/UIGestures) that will show you general iOS gestures. In particular it has a sample that shows how to drag and drop UIViews or how to swipe them around. The sample code includes both driven and fire-n-forget animations. Check it out, its commented and I'd be happy to answer any specific questions you have after reviewing the code.

**Generating a simple circle**

```
// Above Implementation
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

// In viewDidLoad or somewhere
UIView *circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32.0, 32.0, 64.0, 64.0)];
[circleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[circleView.layer setCornerRadius:32.0];
self.view addSubview:circleView];
```

Comment: I checked over some stuff and realized how to find the location of the mouse and have made something to move towards it. However, how would I generate in a simple shape?

Comment: Check my sample code I added. Also checkout the code on github. I place UIViews and UILabels all over the place for each gesture to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to subclass UIView, you can use the touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded methods to accomplish this. Something like:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
        //slightly update location of your object with p.x and p.y cgpoints
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)drawRect{
        //draw your object with updated coordinates
}
```

Comment: Huh, that's actually really cool. Didn't know something such as that was there. How would I actually draw the rect, though?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dot and move it around based on taps all within your `UIViewController` subclass.

Make your dot by creating a `UIView` configured to draw the way you want - look into `CALayer` and setting `dotview.layer.cornerRadius` to make it be round (alternately you can make a `UIView` subclass that overrides `drawRect:` to make the right `CoreGraphics` calls to draw what you want). Set `dotview.center` to position it.

Create a `UITapGestureRecognizer` with an action method in your view controller that updates `dotview.center` as desired. If you want it animated, simply set the property within a view animation call & animation block like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    dotview.center = newposition;
}];
```